# Why wont this code count characters?

Tags: c

Why doesn't this code do anything when i execute it? It's supposed to count characters
i even pressed ctrl+z which someone suggested and it still wont print how many characters after i entered random things. I'm using windows btw

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  long nc;
  nc = 0;

  while (getchar() != EOF)
    ++nc;

  printf("%ld\n", nc);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Works for me: `$ ./keys`
`jasdasjdnasdjasndas`
`20`

Comment: The code is working. You need to give it EOF to stop reading more characters. Then it will print the number of characters inputted.

Comment: it works fine on my Ubuntu, maybe you have some other issue. I dont think you are getting any relevant answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you press `CTRL+Z` and then enter. This triggers `EOF`.

If you want it to end when you press enter, use

```
while( getchar() != '\n' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your sample compiled with UNICODE=1? You have to compare against WEOF then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ^D to provide EOF signal to your program.
Many time ^Z doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `your.exe < your_input.file` or just press `Ctrl+Z` and then `Enter` to get `EOF`

Answer (score -2):

because while getchar() is an infinite loop.

So you never exit the loop untile you kill the process.

Comment: It's not `while (getchar())` -- which wouldn't be infinite either, but merely loop until the `NUL` character -- it's `while (getchar() != EOF)` and so the loop ends when stdin is exhausted.

Comment: you are right, but with keyboard is usually difficult to write an EOF char, while is not with a file as input stream. Then it depends on what you want to count.. even because if you want to count an input file length, reading it with a loop on getchar() is not an elegant way of doing it.